# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am learning Dart and Flutter. Now I am tasting JSON as a persistence method. I get lots of errors, all concerning Types and stuff. This is the latest error I have experienced: `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')`.

This is the class:

```
import './topic.dart';

class Subject {
  String name;
  int order;
  bool isMajor;
  List<Topic> topics;

  Subject({this.name, this.order, this.isMajor, this.topics});

  factory Subject.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Subject(
          name: json['name'],
          order: json['order'],
          isMajor: json['isMajor'],
          topics: [Topic.fromJSON(json['topics'])]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The topic class is this:

```
import './content.dart';

class Topic {
  String name;
  int order;
  List<Content> contents;

  Topic({this.name, this.order, this.contents});

  factory Topic.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json != null) {
      return Topic(
          name: json['name'],
          order: json['order'],
          contents: [Content.fromJSON(json['contents'])]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The error raises here: `[Topic.fromJSON(json['topics'])]`.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Please add what you are getting in json['topics'] and topic class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topics should be

```
topics: List<Topic>.from(json["topics"].map((x) => Topic.fromJson(x))),
```

Because you did not provide `Content` class, I assume it have `name` and `order` attribute 
You can use `Subject subject = subjectFromJson(jsonString);` to parse jsonString

full related class

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final subject = subjectFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Subject subjectFromJson(String str) => Subject.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String subjectToJson(Subject data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Subject {
    String name;
    int order;
    bool isMajor;
    List<Topic> topics;

    Subject({
        this.name,
        this.order,
        this.isMajor,
        this.topics,
    });

    factory Subject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Subject(
        name: json["name"],
        order: json["order"],
        isMajor: json["isMajor"],
        topics: List<Topic>.from(json["topics"].map((x) => Topic.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "order": order,
        "isMajor": isMajor,
        "topics": List<dynamic>.from(topics.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Topic {
    String name;
    int order;
    List<Content> contents;

    Topic({
        this.name,
        this.order,
        this.contents,
    });

    factory Topic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Topic(
        name: json["name"],
        order: json["order"],
        contents: List<Content>.from(json["contents"].map((x) => Content.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "order": order,
        "contents": List<dynamic>.from(contents.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Content {
    String name;
    int order;

    Content({
        this.name,
        this.order,
    });

    factory Content.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
        name: json["name"],
        order: json["order"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "order": order,
    };
}
```

Comment: You can convert your subject Object to a valid json string with subjectToJson before post to server.

Comment: Hey!! where in my app should I call toJson() ??

Comment: If you only query data. you do not need it, you can reference https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

Comment: could you help me with that?? :D Would be glad!

Comment: My question would be: how do I save the JSON as file ??

Comment: You can reference this. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files   , json is string. you can save string diretcly.